# oracle sql loader loading data in different columns in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I have a sample csv file that contains data that i want to load in oracle table.
The sample data is like

```
1,aa,b,c
2,x,yy,zzz
1,aa,b,c
2,x,yy,zzz
```

These are two different records distinguished by first character as '1' and '2', for which I am having a data table in db, that contains the columns of first record and then columns of second record. I tried to load the data using the 'WHEN' clause, but the problem is it don't load data sequentially. It load data for '1' first and then for '2'.
like

```
ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
1   aa      b       c       null    null    null
1   aa      b       c       null    null    null
2   null    null    null    x       yy      zzz
2   null    null    null    x       yy      zzz
```

Here's the loader code:

```
load data
infile 'C:\sample.csv'
APPEND 
INTO TABLE "temp"
WHEN "ID" = '1'
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols
(
Col1,
Col2,       
Col3
)
INTO TABLE "temp"
WHEN "ID" = '2'
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols
(
Col4,
Col5,       
Col6
)
```

I just want to load the data as:

```
ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
1   aa      b       c       null    null    null
2   null    null    null    x       yy      zzz
1   aa      b       c       null    null    null
2   null    null    null    x       yy      zzz
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The data that's loaded is the same as what you expect. There is no inherent order of the data within the table in Oracle; you have to order it when querying, using whatever criteria is appropriate to the client. (I'm guessing you have an index on `ID`, otherwise it might happen to look as you expected, but [only by a fluke](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html)). You seem to be suggesting there's a relationship between pairs of records in the file, and you want to merge them later; but it isn't obvious what that relationship might be.

Comment: If it is your end goal to merge two consecutive records in the CSV file into one row in a table, you could use the options for [assembling logical records from physical records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005509); if they are always paired in the file as you seem to suggest, then `concatenate` might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Every SQL*Loader problem suddenly becomes easier when the code is reimplemented as an external table.

Answer (score 0):

You could load it into a temporary table adding a column that is a sequence number. Then you load it into another table splitting up the columns as you want.

This is not tested but to give you a rough idea:

```
create or replace tmpsequence;

load data
infile 'C:\sample.csv'
APPEND 
INTO TABLE "temp"
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols
(
rec_id "tempsequence.nextval",
id,
Col1,
Col2,       
Col3
)

create table temp2
  select rec_id, id, case when id = "1" then col1 else null end
                   , case when id = "1" then col2 else null end
                   , case when id = "1" then col3 else null end
                   , case when id = "2" then col1 else null end
                   , case when id = "2" then col2 else null end
                   , case when id = "2" then col3 else null end
    from temp
```

Then you should be able to see what you want with

```
select * from temp2 order by rec_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "CONTINUEIF" to assemble logical records from multi-line records in your data file.  This tells SQL*Loader to keep going if a condition is matched.  Here, it says to continue if the first position on the next line is a '2'.  The control file is structured to not load the record_part number:

```
LOAD DATA
infile test.dat
truncate
continueif NEXT (1:1) = '2'
INTO TABLE X_test
fields terminated by ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(rec_part FILLER
,col1 
,col2
,col3
,col4
,col5
,col6
)
```

After loading:

[image]

If the data will ALWAYS be on two lines, replace this line:

```
continueif NEXT (1:1) = '2'
```

with

```
concatenate 2
```

which says each logical record is always 2 rows in the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading data through sqlloader command, then try adding the parameter rows = 1. This will force sqlloader to insert each row of data in the table thus making the file load sequential. By default the row count is 64  which is why you are not getting a sequential load for a small file .

Hope this helps..